# Does vibranium bullet works?

Tags: technology, weapons, energy, materials

Composed of 99.98% vibranium and 0.02% adamantium, both materials claims to be nigh indestructible, non-magnetic and are able to absorb kinetic energy within the molecular bond any excess are loss as neutrino. (okay I made that one up its my world get used to it!)

How can I fire a lethal vibranium bullet using any weapon, conventional or not?

Please use magic sparingly! Other than the said bullet nothing else breaks known laws of physics.

Note: unacceptable answer involved dropping it from height!

Comment: Can you not just form it into the shape of a normal bullet and then use a normal gun? If a normal bullet would be lethal, the vibranium bullet should be too.

Comment: @Brenn_: when the firing pin hammers the explosive thing, the chemical energy is converted into kinetic energy which is the extremely high pressure of air which are completely absorbed by my bullet.

Comment: I think you need to rework the concept... because.. How do you FORGE such a bullet? How do you lift it up? Move it? Load it? This material should be stationary from the second you create it?

Answer (score 2):

A standard fire arm should work fine.

Even though vibranium absorbs kinetic energy<sup>†</sup> and vibrations, the mechanism by which a standard fire arm operates is a build up of pressure behind the projectile.  The projectile can be any substance you choose and vibranium will not detract from this effect to a degree that will significantly degrade the performance of the weapon.

Simply put, the [Wakandan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibranium#Wakandan_variety) variety, simply known as ***vibranium***:

> [...] possesses the ability to absorb all ***vibrations*** [emphasis mine] in the vicinity as well as kinetic energy directed at it. The energy absorbed is stored within the bonds between the molecules that make up the substance. As a result, the more energy vibranium absorbs the tougher it becomes.

The significant difference between a shock or vibration and a pressure differential, in this case, is that vibranium will absorb the shock.  Nothing is said about the effect of the pressure differential.  Presumably this means that there is nothing interesting to note about it.  In other words the effect of a pressure differential on vibranium is static, the same as it is on other naturally occuring elements - meaning a standard weapon should work as expected and the projectile will be ejected, even if it is made of vibranium.

However, one benefit (potentially also a caveat) of the bullet being made of vibranium is that the shot will likely be silent - without a silencing device:

> There are limits to the capacity of the energy that can be stored, and although the exact limitations are not yet known, there have been a few examples. One such instance was when the oil conglomerate Roxxon discovered that a small island in the South Atlantic had a foundation composed of vibranium. Due to this, Roxxon found it necessary to destroy the island and so blew it up with bombs. Unable to absorb the force of the explosions, the vibranium was destroyed, ***but it did succeed in entirely absorbing the sound made by the explosion*** [emphasis mine], preventing damage to the surrounding area.

***As long as*** the firing of the weapon is not powerful enough to destroy vibranium.  It is not clear from the description how powerful the explosion was that destroyed the vibranium on the island.

<sup>†</sup> Presumably this is referring to [impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics)) energy, rather than the more general term, [kinetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy) energy.

---

As for special kinds of weapons, your guess is as good as mine.

But as I was reading about each kind of vibranium, the standard Wakandan variety as well as Antarctic variety, known as [anti-metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibranium#Antarctic_variety), the idea came into the back of my mind about the possible interplay between the two isotopes.

The first absorbs and stores energy, making it tougher.

While the second actually produces vibrations which liquify other metals.

Presumably anti-metal does not liquify vibranium, but makes it stronger, however my suspicion is that there may be an interesting kind of oscillation or feedback between the two isotopes that could be exploited to produce very stange and powerfull effects.

The most obvious would ***seem to be a bomb***, similar to a nuclear weapon, which by blasting the two metals together would produce an exotic reaction when the atoms of the two metals <del>fuse</del> come into close, molecular proximity, one vibrating the other storing until it breaks, however the interesting part is what happens when the reaction begins.

> Anti-Metal is able to become an artificial and unstable form of the Wakandan variety of vibranium through certain particle bombardments on it.

The result is explicitly unstable, however, we are talking about two exotic isotopes and the bombardment is coming from particles of an isotope of the same element.  So it is not clear whether this would catastrophically explode or do something much stranger - like make a black hole perhaps? :D

One may never know...

Answer (score 1):

**Ask Captain America how to do it!**

It's quite clear that Vibranium does not absorb *all* of the kinetic energy imparted on it, or else Captain America could not wield it.  Clearly he understands the trick.

Most likely, the answer is that Vibranium only damps high frequency shocks, such as strikes or bullet impacts.  Accordingly, you might get away with pushing the bullet with CO2, like a paintballgun.

Likewise, Captain America's trick of throwing his shield would work pretty poorly if it couldn't impact anything without absorbing the force, so he also knows how to make sure the bullet actually has some impulse when it reaches its target.

Answer (score 1):

The thing with "absorb kinetic energy" is that it can't be in a way that creates an immovable object.

If the shield (or the bullet for that matter) would absorb any kinetic energy, it would be impossible accelerate it. The shield won't be able to bounce!

Instead, we should be thinking about it absorbing all deformation. The object made of vibranium can't be deformed. That means that every time the shield bounces it is a perfect elastic collision as far as the shield is concerned.

Consider the case where the shield is held against a bomb blast, it will protect the user, [but it still pushes back](https://youtu.be/QZkqC4Lz8dU?t=50s).

With that in mind, yes, you can make a gun that fires bullets made of vibranium.